# what to do if android studio showing Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.bintray.com/samanjafaridotir/easyCountDownTimerTextview/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/samanjafaridotir/easyCountDownTimerTextview/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/samanjafaridotir/easyCountDownTimerTextview/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
> Could not resolve com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> > Failed to list versions for com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.bintray.com/farhanahmed95/maven/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/farhanahmed95/maven/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/farhanahmed95/maven/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD GRADLE

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:0.9.18"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'  // Crashlytics plugin

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/samanjafaridotir/easyCountDownTimerTextview'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/farhanahmed95/maven/'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.dokka"
```